# ElasticClient Dispose

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm new to this.  I'm working with ElasticClient (.Net) and I was curious if:

1. Is it thread safe?  I assume so because it uses pooling.
2. Should I do anything to clean up the client resources when I'm done?  It does not implement IDisposable.

Thanks!

Bob

Answer (score 3):

On thread safety: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/23

> The ElasticClient holds a single IConnection responsible for doing
>   async and sync http calls.  The IConnection does not reuse
>   httprequests and uses thread local state for data thats being passed
>   around during the stages of the request. It should thus be thread
>   safe.

On disposing: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/101

> ElasticClient is almost stateless except for a static CLR type info
>   cache that is threadsafe so you can even use one client over threads.
>   Disposing is also handled by Nest and ElasticClient only exposes
>   POCO's.

Comment: If for some reason you need to create several clients for a short time, the absence of Dispose or at least close connection is becoming a problem as you can run out of resources really fast and you have no control on the lifetime of the connection.